# Inserting and retrieving text with newlines

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea, newline

I have a slight problem with inserting newlines in textareas. After I submit the form the text in database shows something like:

"text\r\nfor" (i'm on windows)

For the following text: 
"text 
for"

Then after I retrieve the respective text from the database in the textarea it shows:

"text\r\n\for"

I'm using PHP and put the text in the textarea like so:

```
<textarea name="post_content">{$post_content}</textarea>
```

I want it to render properly with the newline character instead of \n or \r\n .

Comment: Try to strip '\r' with `str_replace()` before you echo the content. EX: `str_replace("\r\n", "\n");`

Comment: I'm confused now. Do you just want all the `\r` removed or do you actually have the 2 symbols \ and n instead of a new line in your text area?

Comment: I want \n or \r\n (windows counterpart) to render as a new line instead of a plain "\r\n\" text.

Comment: If you have `\r\n\ ` in your database as 5 separate symbols, something is wrong with the code you use to input this data into your database. The newline `\n` is never stored as two separate characters anywhere. It's just a shorthand for programming languages to tell the compiler or interpreter that you want a newline symbol here. For instance `echo strlen("\n");` will output `1` as `\n` is interpreted as a single new line character. You might want to show us the code where you process the textarea's contents and put it into your database.

Comment: I'm using mysql_escape_string on all variables i'm sending in the query. Could that be the cause ? And yes, i'm seeing \r\n in my database strings.

Comment: Yes. mysql_escape_string does replace your newlines with a backslash and a `n`. But this replacement is just for the transport to the database. The database will usually re-replace those two symbols into one newline. From this point on you should have just a newline in your database. If you show some code, we might be able to help you. It can be difficult even for experienced programmers not to get lost in all the different languages involved.

Comment: The code is rather big, I'm using PDO and two more classes besides this. Thanks for the help anyway :) now I know what the problem is.

Comment: You are not by any chance using mysqli and prepared statements? In this case using mysql_escape_string will mess up your values and you will probably end up with a problem like you descriped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text stored in the database has a single `\` which means to escape the `n`, which happens before a newline can be rendered.

The easiest fix is to store the text with a second `\`, like this:

```
text\\r\\nfor
```

This would then be rendered by PHP as:

```
text\r\nfor
```

Which would create the HTML with a newline.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the problem :D, gonna make the necessary changes.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :(, now I get rn in the textarea when I str_replace \r\n with \\r\\n

Comment: I found what what my problem is, i'm using mysql_escape_string and it prepends a backslash to every \n and \r character :(

Comment: so `mysql_escape_string()` is automatically turning `\n` into `\\n`?

Comment: Yes. `mysql_escape_string` escapes all characters with special meaning for the transport. If you want the string `\n` (two characters) to show up as such in the database, use `mysql_escape_string` on them. The backslash is a special character that needs escaping. If you apply `mysql_escape_string` on a newline character, it will be replaced by the two characters `\n`. If you applay `mysql_escape_string` yet again, you'll end up with `\\n`.

Answer (score 0):

My final bet is that you are using prepared statements and additionally escape your value before inputting, like

```
// newlines will be replaced with '\n' here
$value = mysql_escape_string($_POST["value"]);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (value) VALUES (?)");

// mysql will insert the contents of $value literally. 
// so instead of a newline, you will have '\n' (two characters) in your database
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value);

// if you did this statement, everything would be fine. mysql would see your '\n'
// and replace it back to a newline. 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable (value) VALUES ('$value')");
```

If this is the case, you don't have to escape your values. `bindParam` will do this for you. Here is some example of the two ways you can safely transfer user input into your database.

```
// not escaped 
$value = $_POST["value"];

// escape characters that have special meaning for mysql
$value2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST["value2"]);

// $value2 gets inserted into the query-string. we needed to 
// escape it's contents to not mix it up with actual SQL code.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (value, value2) VALUES (?, '$value2')");

// $value gets inserted using bindParam. everything is fine here.
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, I just fixed my issue 30 mins ago and it turned out that my PDO class was preparing my queries and I needn't escape them again. thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is encode the new lines in the value that you display in the textarea. You can do this in server side or client sides html_encode function. So basically you replace all 
`\n`, `\r`, `\r\n` with `<br>.` Let me know if it works

Comment: A `<br/>` tag inside a `<textarea>` will not display as newline. It will just show the text `<br/>`. Don't replace newlines with `<br/>` inside `<textarea>` tags.

Comment: Right it won't.. Sorry I meant in html not inside the textarea.. I guess I did not read the problem well.